# '{': no matching token found

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm currently working on a c++ project in visual studio 2019 and keep getting the error: "C1075 '{': no matching token found", I know this is for when you open a brace and don't close it but this doesn't occur in my code, I have a few functions in the header file and it only gives me one instance of the error, but when I comment out the code for the function it tells me the error occurs at, it gives me the same error for the function above it. This is the function I get the error at initially,

```
void WriteBody()
{
   asio::async_write(m_socket, asio::buffer(&qMessagesOut.front().body.data(), 
     m_qMessagesOut.front().body.size()),
      [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
      {
        if (!ec)
        {
          m_qMessagesOut.pop_front();
          if (!m_qMessagesOut.empty())
            WriteHeader();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[" << id << "] Write Body Fail.\n";
            m_socket.close();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a )

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `)`

```cpp
void WriteBody()
{
   // to match this |
   //               v
   asio::async_write(m_socket, asio::buffer(&qMessagesOut.front().body.data(), 
     m_qMessagesOut.front().body.size()),
      [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
      {
        if (!ec)
        {
          m_qMessagesOut.pop_front();
          if (!m_qMessagesOut.empty())
            WriteHeader();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[" << id << "] Write Body Fail.\n";
            m_socket.close();
        }
     }
     )
  // ^
  // |   
}
```